# Multiple SOAP services at same URL (different version of the same)

Tags: java, spring, soap, jax-ws

I have a need to support multiple versions of SOAP endpoint with the same URL, is this possible?
Soap classes have been generated from a third party wsdl.

In web.xml I have:

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>soap</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSSpringServlet</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>soap</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/soap/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

In my applicationContext.xml I have the following:

```
<wss:binding url="/soap/StuffService/">
    <wss:service>
        <ws:service bean="#stuffV1"/>
    </wss:service>
</wss:binding>

<bean id="stuffV1" class="package.soap.StuffSoapEndpointV1"/>
```

And I have a java class:

```
@WebService(
        portName = "BasicHttpBinding_IStuffService",
        serviceName = "StuffService",
        endpointInterface = "package.soap.stuff.IStuffService",
        targetNamespace = "http://stuff.example.org/Integration/Service/Outgoing/v1",
        wsdlLocation = "/WEB-INF/Integration.Service.Outgoing.v1.IStuff.wsdl")
@ApiOperation(value = "Stuff Service")
public class StuffSoapEndpointV1 implements IStuffService {
```

Is it possible to add a second version to the same url? Something in the lines of:

```
<wss:binding url="/soap/StuffService/">
    <wss:service>
        <ws:service bean="#stuffV1"/>
        <ws:service bean="#stuffV2"/>
    </wss:service>
</wss:binding>

<bean id="stuffV1" class="package.soap.StuffSoapEndpointV1"/>
<bean id="stuffV2" class="package.soap.StuffSoapEndpointV2"/>


@WebService(
        portName = "BasicHttpBinding_IStuffService",
        serviceName = "StuffService",
        endpointInterface = "package.soap.stuff.IStuffService",
        targetNamespace = "http://stuff.example.org/Integration/Service/Outgoing/v2",
        wsdlLocation = "/WEB-INF/Integration.Service.Outgoing.v2.IStuff.wsdl")
@ApiOperation(value = "Stuff Service")
public class StuffSoapEndpointV2 implements IStuffService {
```

That doesn't work. Multiple ws:service tags are not allowed, same for wss:service and wss:binding with same url. Also I think that portName and serviceName combo should be unique, but they need to be same as in the wsdl which doesn't come from us.